# Filtering data and calculating for subsets with the output dependent on excluded data

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame where monthly data `month` on herbivore parasitism  `result` for various types of parasitoid order 'psitorder' with levels "Hymenoptera" or "Diptera". The `result` is either "p" for parasitized herbivore, "a" if the herbivore grew to adult, or there is no data "" because the herbivore died in captivity.

```
  df<-data.frame(month= c(rep(1, each=8), rep(2, each=6), 
      rep(3, each=6)),result= c(rep("p",each=3),rep("a",each=3) , 
      rep("",each=2),rep("p",each=3),rep("a",each=2), 
      rep("",each=1),rep("a",each=3), rep("",each=3)),
      psitorder= c(rep("Hymenoptera",each=2),rep("Diptera",each=1),
      rep("",each=5),rep("Hymenoptera",each=1),rep("Diptera",each=3), 
      rep("",each=2),rep("",each=6)))
```

I need two separate dataframes that calculate percent parasitism `psit_freq` for each month subset separately for each level of `psitorder`.

I have tried:

```
Hymenoptera_output<- 
  df  
  filter(psitorder!= "Diptera")%>%
  group_by(continuous_month)%>%
  summarise(psit_freq = sum(result == "psit")/sum(result== 
 "adult",result == "psit"))

Diptera_output<- 
  df  
  filter(psitorder!= "Hymenoptera")%>%
  group_by(continuous_month)%>%
  summarise(psit_freq = sum(result == "psit")/sum(result== 
 "adult",result == "psit"))
```

I do not get the correct output. The output excludes non-hymenoptera or diptera data needed to calculated the `psit_freq` properly.

I need the outputs to appear as follows:

```
Hymenoptera_output<- data.frame(month= c(1,2,3), psit_freq= c(2/6, 
 1/5, 0))
Diptera_output<- data.frame(month= c(1,2,3), psit_freq= c(1/6, 
 3/5, 0))

Hymenoptera_output

#  month psit_freq
#1     1 0.3333333
#2     2 0.2000000
#3     3 0.0000000

Diptera_output

#  month psit_freq
#1     1 0.1666667
#2     2 0.6000000
#3     3 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(month) %>% 
    summarise(hym_freq = sum(psitorder == 'Hymenoptera')/sum(result %in% c('p', 'a')), 
              dip_freq = sum(psitorder == 'Diptera')/sum(result %in% c('p', 'a')))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  month  hym_freq  dip_freq
#  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1 0.3333333 0.1666667
#2     2 0.2000000 0.6000000
#3     3 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: Actually in my original dataframe the `psitorder` variable has NAs as a result of making that variable with entries conditional on another column. All data that is not classified as Diptera or Hymenoptera was given a NA designation.   I think the NAs in this column may be the reason my output is not what I would expect. Currently my output, given your method, is reporting NAs for most entries. Any idea on how to remedy this issue?

Comment: You can use `na.rm=T` in `sum`. For instance `sum(psitorder == 'Hymenoptera', na.rm=T)`, likewise for other *sums*.

Comment: Wonderful, this is great, thank you for the timely response.